# BASH - getopts not working properly

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I'm currently having problems with my script. Basically, what I want to happen is when I execute `./apache_new_vhost.sh -a -d google.com`, it will create a file and directories and if I use the -r option, it should delete.

The script was able to use the functions like add_vhost. It could create a configuration and folder however the filename is empty because it could not read the value I passed to `$domain`.

```
while getopts ":a:r:d:h" opt; do
        case $opt in
                a)      action=add_vhost
                        ;;
                r)      action=remove_vhost
                        ;;
                d)      domain=$OPTARG
                        ;;
                h)      usage
                        exit 1
                        ;;
                \?)     echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG"
                        usage
                        exit 1
                        ;;
                :)      echo "Error: option -$OPTARG requires an argument."
                        usage
                        exit 1
                        ;;
        esac
done

#if [ -z $domain ]; then
#       usage
#       exit 1
if [ $action == "add_vhost" ]; then
    echo $action $domain
elif [ $action == "remove_vhost" ]; then
    echo $action $domain
fi
```

Comment: Please don't include your full code. Insert a _minimal working example_ that shows the problem you're encountering. In fact, while you're stripping your code down to pinpoint the actual problem, you might find out you're able to correct the mistake on your own. Please see the section [_Before asking about problematic code_ on the Bash tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: Hi @gniourf_gniourf, my bad. I'll remove the rest of the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are processed in the order you specify them on the command line. So in your example, `case a)` is processed first, and calls your `add_vhost` function right then.

But the `d)` case hasn't been processed yet, so you haven't set `domain`.

You need to change your logic a bit. Rather than calling your functions directly from the case statement, save what action was selected. i.e.:

```
 a)   action="add_vhost"
      ;;
```

Then after the case, check that you do have an `action` selected, and call that function.

Comment: Hi @Mat, I followed your advice but it is still not getting anything from the `$domain`. The script didn't echo the `google.com`.

`# ./apache_new_vhost.sh -a -d google.com
# add_vhost`

Comment: Hi @Mat, my apologies. The code above has been updated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi @Mat, yes, sorry about that. But going back, it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Your getopt options are wrong. Only `d` has a parameter. Try `d:arh`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your script you expect argument after option `-a`. So when you execute your script by

```
./apache_new_vhost.sh -a -d google.com
```

then `-d` will consider as argument given to `-a` option. So your second argument discarded.To solve it just give any argument after `-a` (ex:  ./apache_new_vhost.sh -a 1 -d google.com )option or make changes in your `getopt`

```
while getopts ":ar:d:h" opt; do
```